# Cannot connect to a VPN on Ubuntu 20.04.2 using a specific wifi

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

My university provides a High Performance Computing cluster, which is only accessible if you are connected to the University's wi-fi or if you are connected to the university's VPN.

I would like to access the VPN from my accomodation, however when I try to connect to the VPN via Settings -> Network -> VPN, I get the message: Connection failed.

The weird thing is that I have been able to connect to the VPN using another wifi. Also, I remember the wifi provider telling me that the University VPN used some older protocol which they did not accept, but I have flatmates which manage to connect to the VPN using PuTTy on Windows.

I wanted to ask whether anyone knows any trick to get around this, as I am aware that I am not a VPN network expert. Ideally, it would be great if I could just manage to get my machine to directly connect to the university VPN. However, I would also be happy to get a "dirtier" trick working, where maybe I connect via VPN to another machine, which in turn connects to the University VPN.

Also please let me know if you are aware of other communities where I could find some help. Thank you in advance, that would make my work much easier!

Comment: Hi. Just a thought. Some WLAN providers block certain TCP/UDP ports. This could prevent a connection from being established.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If that is the case, is there anything I could do to bypass the issue?

Comment: This is difficult to answer in general. That depends on various factors. In principle, my suggestion would be to set up a VPN server in your home network that listens to permitted ports (80,443). A connection to the campus network must then be established on this. Appropriate routing must then be provided to transport the packets between the campus network and you. This is now only very roughly described. And unfortunately I can't give you any details about it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and I ll try to get see if I can set up what you suggest. Please let me know if I can provide any useful information

Comment: You're welcome. I'll be on vacation for the next three weeks, and unfortunately I can't help then. But useful information is: What kind of application are you using in the campus network (CLI/WEB/CS/...)? What kind of VPN are you using to connect to the campus network (openvpn/ipsec/...)? How is your Linux knowledge?

Comment: Dear Winnie, sorry for my late reply, but I managed to get the VPN working through an alternative configuration (openVPN). This was suggested by a friend, but again, thank you so much for your availability in helping out!

Comment: No problem with the late reply. The main thing is that you got it working. Would you post your solution as well?